# How can i solve Error in running NodeJs program

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to convert geojson file to shapefile. but after running this code I receive this error. how can I resolve it ??

```
................... server.js
var geojson2shape = require('geojson2shape')
// a shapefile is actually multiple files. geojson2shape will output a zipped version if specified.
var zip = true
geojson2shape(__dirname+'/polygon.geojson', __dirname+'/polygon.shp', function(err){
  if(err) throw err
})
..................  error

events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\test\polygon.dbf'
  Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:120:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:146:23) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\test\\polygon.dbf'
}
```

Comment: What have you tried fo far?? Also without bare minimum code its very difficult to guide you.

Comment: If you inspect the error carefully, it indicates the file 'C:\test\polygon.dbf' is missing

Comment: Did you make sure that the file you are trying to open exists at path `C:\test\polygon.dbf` ?

Comment: I'm trying to convert geojson file to shapefile. but after running this code I receive this error   var geojson2shape = require('geojson2shape')
// a shapefile is actually multiple files. geojson2shape will output a zipped version if specified.
var zip = true
geojson2shape(__dirname+'/polygons.geojson', __dirname+'/polygons.shp', function(err){
  if(err) throw err
})

Comment: @hamed You are trying to access `C:\test\polygon.dbf` file but in the code there is no any code related to reading the above file

Answer (score 0):

The error can be due to any of the below reason check one by one:-

```
1.fs.readFile() is async, if you are using this you need to pass
 callback as well. OR you can try readFilesync()

2.The error is due to the incorrect file location('C:\test\polygon.dbf') 

3.file doesn't have read permission.You can try with any other file path.
```

> As you are trying to read database file so you can try some DBF
> Parser npm module for reading or any other operation with it.

One I can suggest you is **node-dbf**

> npm i node-dbf
>
> [you can checkout this link for more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dbf)

Hope it will help!